# Entity framework adds an extra condition on where clause

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have identified that when the following expression is executed:

```
int aNum = 52;
var myArtifacts = mydbcontext.artifacts.Where(a => a.ParentID == aNum ).ToList();
```

on mysql the query executed is:

```
SELECT
  `Extent1`.`ID`, 
  `Extent1`.`ParentID`
FROM `artifacts` AS `Extent1`
WHERE ((`Extent1`.`ParentID` = 52) AND (52 IS NOT NULL));
```

Can anyone explain please why this last extra condition is added?

> AND (52 IS NOT NULL))

Comment: Hmm, I've seen this for parameters, but not for constants. Try setting the  `DbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics` to `true`.

Comment: Actually it was a parameter, sorry. I just put a number here to make it simpler

Comment: What is the data type of the parameter?

Comment: integer. So... i seem to get it now... checks for nullable types?

Comment: integer or nullable integer?

Comment: no, its just int, which is clearly not nullable

Comment: @shA.t, if you mean why I changed it, I did change it to a variable expression to make the question more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics(v=vs.113).aspx

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether database null semantics are exhibited when comparing two operands, both of which are potentially nullable. The default value is false. For example (operand1 == operand2) will be translated as: (operand1 = operand2) if UseDatabaseNullSemantics is true, respectively (((operand1 = operand2) AND (NOT (operand1 IS NULL OR operand2 IS NULL))) OR ((operand1 IS NULL) AND (operand2 IS NULL))) if UseDatabaseNullSemantics is false.

If the current behaviour is bothering you, consider setting `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` to `true`.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
    }
}
```

or

```
myDbContext.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

Comment: No actually the behavior does not bother me. As far as I know, it does not even add any extra processing time (at least not notable). Would you suggest a reason I should change it.  My initial question was basically out of curiosity

Comment: I suppose that it's just a matter of preference, if you want to rely on the database null semantics or not. It's recommended to stick to the defaults, unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: your answer is probably accepted, but as I specified, in my case the one operand is not "potentially nullable", so it does not explain the given situation.